# how to convert __SwiftValue to Int or String from web3swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have data fetched from a network request, which is `["0": 1]`. I want to parse the value `1` into either `Int` or `String`.

If I try to cast the value to either `String`, `Int`, `NSNumber`, or `NSString`, I invariably get the following error:

```swift
let value = data["0"] as! Int
```

> Could not cast value of type '__SwiftValue' (0x7fff873c5bd8) to 'NSNumber' (0x7fff86d8c858).

or `NSString`.

When I checked:

```swift
let isValidJSON = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data)
```

this returns `false`, which means the following fails as well:

```swift
let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

How do I parse this?

I'm using a library named web3swift and the data is returned from this [function](https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift/blob/5484e81580219ea491d48e94f6aef6f18d8ec58f/Sources/web3swift/Web3/Web3%2BReadingTransaction.swift#L106):

```swift
public func call(transactionOptions: TransactionOptions? = nil) throws -> [String: Any] {
     return try self.callPromise(transactionOptions: transactionOptions).wait()
}
```

And [callPromise](https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift/blob/5484e81580219ea491d48e94f6aef6f18d8ec58f/Sources/web3swift/Web3/Web3%2BReadingTransaction.swift#L32) in turn returns the following:

```swift
public func callPromise(transactionOptions: TransactionOptions? = nil) -> Promise<[String: Any]>
```

Comment: What is type is `data`? Where did you get it from?

Comment: The value cannot be a string, note the missing double quotes. According to the error `data` is not a dictionary. Did try decode the JSON with `Decodable`?

Comment: I updated the question to include the function I'm using to return `data`.

Comment: Why not `print(data["0"])` and find out what it really is?

Comment: `print(data["0"])` returns `Optional(1)` and `print(type(of: data["0"]))` returns `Optional<Any>`.

Comment: From reading the [library's code](https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift/blob/5484e81580219ea491d48e94f6aef6f18d8ec58f/Sources/web3swift/EthereumABI/ABIDecoding.swift#L35), the value could be one of many types, most likely `BigUInt` or `BigInt`.

Comment: @Sweeper thank you, `BigUInt` was it. If you want to write it in the answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged into the [library's code](https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift/blob/5484e81580219ea491d48e94f6aef6f18d8ec58f/Sources/web3swift/EthereumABI/ABIDecoding.swift#L35), and found that the library decodes the integers in the response as either `BigInt` or `BigUInt`. You should know which kind of data you are expecting.

You should try casting to one of those types instead, and since `BigInt` or `BigUInt` can store numbers that are arbitrarily big, you probably shouldn't convert them to an `Int`. You can convert them to `String`s (not sure why you want to) using [`String.init(_:)`](http://attaswift.github.io/BigInt/Extensions/String.html#/s:SS6BigIntEySSAA0A4UIntVcfc).

This is not one of the types of object that `JSONSerialization` recognises, so `JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject` returns false.